# How to check the value already excists or not in sqlite db in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my application I am saving a bill number in SQLite database. Before I add a new bill number how to check if the bill number exists in the DB.

My main class code is,

```
 String bill_no_excist_or_not = db.billno_exist_or_not(""+et_bill_number.getText().toString());
 Log.v("Bill No", ""+bill_no_excist_or_not);
```

My DB Code,

```
String billno_exist_or_not(String bill_number){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_BILL_DETAILS, new String[] { KEY_BILL_NUMBER }, KEY_BILL_NUMBER + "=?"
                    + new String[] { bill_number }, null, null, null, null);

//after this i don't know how to return the values

    return bill_number;
}
```

I don't know how to check the values which is already available or not in DB. Can any one know please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function that helps you to find whether the value is available in database or not.

Here please replace your query with my query..

```
public int isUserAvailable(int userId)
    {
        int number = 0;
        Cursor c = null;
        try
        {
            c = db.rawQuery("select user_id from user_table where user_id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(userId)});

            if(c.getCount() != 0)
                number = c.getCount();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(c!=null) c.close();
        }
        return number;
    }
```

Comment: here am not understand clearly please explain me in this `if(c.getCount() != 0)
                number = c.getCount();
        }` code.

Comment: If your query successfully run and find match result then c.getCount returns the number of match result ... So we can conclude that there are some records in database..

Answer (score 1):

Make your `KEY_BILL_NUMBER` column in your table `UNIQUE` and you can just insert using `insertWithOnConflict` with the flag `SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE`